# Function parameters syntax in Julia

Tags: http-headers, httprequest, julia

The [HTTP.jl](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/blob/master/src/HTTP.jl) library provides the function `HTTP.request` with the following signature `HTTP.request(method, url [, headers [, body]]; <keyword arguments>])`

I am not sure what this syntax mean `url [, headers [, body]]`

In particular, what I am trying to do is make a GET request like: `https://example.org/api?api_key=my_api_key` so I am calling: `HTTP.request("GET", "https://example.org/api")`

Now how do I specify my `api_key` in the header?

Comment: the notation using square brackets is very common in programming in general, to indicate optional arguments, and with angle brackets to indicate required arguments, where these need to be denoted as such explicitly. With regard to your particular example, you can either call this method like `request(method, url)` or like `request(method, url, headers`) or like `request(method, url, headers, body)`, but not `request(method, url, body)` for example. Also, you're missing a square bracket above, so I don't know whether keyword arguments are optional in themselves or required if a header is used.

Comment: Note that this notation is one describing 'syntax' and is intended for human users, this is not "code". You can confirm this notation refers to optional positional arguments and optional keyword arguments if you look up the function definition on line 296 in the link you just posted.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I am sorry. I am fairly new to programming and didn't know this notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this like this:

`julia
HTTP.request("GET", "https://example.org/api"; query = Dict(:api_key => "my_api_key"))`

Comment: Ahh! I was passing this query parameter directly as in `HTTP.request("GET", "https://example.org/api", Dict(:api_key => "my_api_key"))` because I thought it is not a keyword argument. Thank you!

Comment: @kishlaya note that in julia, keyword arguments can be distinguished from positional ones in the function definition because they are separated by a semicolon. When you're _calling_ the function you can use the same syntax, but you don't _have_ to, and you can simply use a comma before the first keyword argument instead; but using a semicolon is just good style.